# Publish on /mobile_base/commands/velocity for moving the turtlebot

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys, I'm using gazebo an I want to publish message on /mobile_base/commands/velocity for moving the turtlebot but I  don't succeded.

this is my class

```
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from geometry_msgs.msg import Vector3

class rosact(object):
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('act')
        self._pub = rospy.Publisher('mobile_base/commands/velocity',Twist,queue_size=10)
        rospy.spin()

    def write(self,linear,angular):
        self._pub.publish(Twist(Vector3(linear[0],linear[1],linear[2]),
                   Vector3(angular[0],angular[1],angular[2])))

def main():
    act=rosact()
    act.write([0.2,0,0],[0,0,0])
    

if __name__== '__main__':
    main()
```

Help me,please

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251581/publish-on-/mobile_base/commands/velocity-for-moving-the-turtlebot/) by [Marcosdp](https://answers.ros.org/users/28979/marcosdp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In case you wonder why write is never called, rospy.spin() is a blocking function. A short sleep (rospy.sleep(1)) should be enough to create the publisher (and a sleep after the publish ensures that the message is also sent.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcosdp](https://answers.ros.org/users/28979/marcosdp/) on 2017-01-09**:
Yes, it works.. Thanks.. I'have another question:
Can I implement Asyncio with rospy.Spin (),for doing a asynchronous call(because I need to acquire the results of sensors and the result of a  algorithm of decision.

Thanks